# Nesting a function in R until a condition is met

Tags: r, algorithm, nested

I am looking for an efficient way to nest the same function in R until a condition is met. I hope the following example illustrates my problem clearly.
Consider the function

*f(x) = x^2 + 1*, with x > 1.

Denote

f^{(k)}(x) = f(f(f(...f(x)))),

where the function f is evaluated k times within itself. Let M > 0, with M given.
Is there any efficient routine in R to determine the minimum value of k such that f^{(k)}(2) > M?
Thank you.

Comment: I think it would be more natural to write a recursive function

Comment: Hi @Moody_Mudskipper. In my original problem, I tried to write a recursive function. However, this recursion is not possible. For this reason, I am examining alternative approaches. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: mmm... you should show an example showing why recursion wouldn't be working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing special for that.  Just use a loop:

```
function(x, M) {
  k <- 0
  repeat {
    x <- x^2 + 1
    k <- k + 1
    if (x > M)
      break
  }
  k
}
```

Not particularly efficient, but often the overhead of evaluating `f` will be greater than the overhead of the loop.  If that's not the case (and it might not be for this particular `f`), I'd suggest doing the equivalent thing in C or C++ (perhaps using `Rcpp`).

Answer (score 0):

This would be the recursive approach:

```
# 2^2  + 1 == 5
# 5^2  + 1 == 26
# 26^2 + 1 == 677

f <- function(x,M,k=0){
  if(x <= M) k <- f(x^2 + 1,M=M,k+1)
  return(k)
}
f(2,3)    # 1
f(2,10)   # 2
f(2,50)   # 3
f(2,700)  # 4
```

Comment: Given your approaches, Moody_Mudskipper and user2554330, I see that the problem was simpler than I thought. Thank you both.